# How to use JSON schema validation against JSON document having arrays?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have json document which contains three main elements along with sub elements. These elements also have arrays. I validated this document with json schema but I am not sure if there is any simple way to get rid of repeating schema for arrays as the current schema is too long.

JSON Schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "/",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "book": {
      "id": "book",
      "type": "array",
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "0",
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "isbn": {
              "id": "isbn",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "title": {
              "id": "title",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "price": {
              "id": "price",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "categories": {
              "id": "categories",
              "type": "array",
              "items": [
                {
                  "id": "0",
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "category": {
                      "id": "category",
                      "type": "string"
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "id": "1",
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "category": {
                      "id": "category",
                      "type": "string"
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "id": "2",
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "category": {
                      "id": "category",
                      "type": "string"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            "warehouse": {
              "id": "warehouse",
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "location": {
                  "id": "location",
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "aisle": {
                  "id": "aisle",
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "shelf": {
                  "id": "shelf",
                  "type": "string"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "isbn",
            "title",
            "price",
            "categories",
            "category",
            "warehouse"
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "1",
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "isbn": {
              "id": "isbn",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "title": {
              "id": "title",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "price": {
              "id": "price",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "categories": {
              "id": "categories",
              "type": "array",
              "items": [
                {
                  "id": "0",
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "category": {
                      "id": "category",
                      "type": "string"
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "id": "1",
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "category": {
                      "id": "category",
                      "type": "string"
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "id": "2",
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "category": {
                      "id": "category",
                      "type": "string"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            "warehouse": {
              "id": "warehouse",
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "location": {
                  "id": "location",
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "aisle": {
                  "id": "aisle",
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "shelf": {
                  "id": "shelf",
                  "type": "string"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "isbn": {
              "id": "isbn",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "title": {
              "id": "title",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "price": {
              "id": "price",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "categories": {
              "id": "categories",
              "type": "array",
              "items": [
                {
                  "id": "0",
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "category": {
                      "id": "category",
                      "type": "string"
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "id": "1",
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "category": {
                      "id": "category",
                      "type": "string"
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "id": "2",
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "category": {
                      "id": "category",
                      "type": "string"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            "warehouse": {
              "id": "warehouse",
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "location": {
                  "id": "location",
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "aisle": {
                  "id": "aisle",
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "shelf": {
                  "id": "shelf",
                  "type": "string"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "required": [
        "0",
        "1",
        "2"
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "book"
  ]
}
```

And JSON document:

```
{  
   "book":[  
      {  
         "isbn":"0-672-33751-7",
         "title":"Unity Game Development",
         "price":"$55.99",
         "categories":[  
            {  
               "category":"Game Development"
            },
            {  
               "category":"Unit Game Engine"
            },
            {  
               "category":"Beginner to Intermediate"
            }
         ],
         "warehouse":{  
            "location":"North Warehouse",
            "aisle":"A16",
            "shelf":"3"
         }
      },
      {  
         "isbn":"978-0-9871530-7-4",
         "title":"Jquery: Novice to Ninja",
         "price":"$39.95",
         "categories":[  
            {  
               "category":"JavaScript"
            },
            {  
               "category":"jQuery"
            },
            {  
               "category":"Web Development"
            }
         ],
         "warehouse":{  
            "location":"North Warehouse",
            "aisle":"W03",
            "shelf":"6"
         }
      },
      {  
         "isbn":"0-538-74477-4",
         "title":"Programming Logic and Design",
         "price":"$89.99",
         "categories":[  
            {  
               "category":"Programming"
            },
            {  
               "category":"JavaScript"
            },
            {  
               "category":"Computer Logic"
            }
         ],
         "warehouse":{  
            "location":"South Warehouse",
            "aisle":"B44",
            "shelf":"1"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a lot of issues with this schema.  I suggest you read http://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/ to get a better understanding of JSON Schema.  Below is the corrected schema.  I'll give some brief advice, but not a lot of explanation.  Go read that link for more info.

1. `id` is required to be a absolute URL. "/" is not valid
2. Don't use `id` anywhere other than the root of the document.  It has some unexpected properties.  It's best to just avoid it.
3. The `items` keyword should be a schema not an array of schemas.  The form you are using is not intended for arrays with a single type of item.
4. The `required` keyword applies only to properties in the schema it appears in.  Sub-schemas need to define their own `required` properties.
5. The `required` keyword does not work on arrays.  Use `minItems` and `maxItems` instead.

---

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "book": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "isbn": { "type": "string" },
          "title": { "type": "string" },
          "price": { "type": "string" },
          "categories": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "category": { "type": "string" }
              },
              "required": ["category"]
            }
          },
          "warehouse": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "location": { "type": "string" },
              "aisle": { "type": "string" },
              "shelf": { "type": "string" }
            }
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "isbn", "title", "price", "categories", "warehouse"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "required": ["book"]
}
```